# Fixing seeds in keras tanks accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I'm following [this example on how to use Keras to build a CNN trained on MNIST](https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/). I modified it so that the batch size is 20, the number of classes is 10, and the number of epochs is 3. I also only use the first 1000 images from the dataset. This is all to decrease the time spent training and to lower the accuracy a bit (for separate reasons).

Of course training as-is is not fully reproducible. Here are 3 results from training:

```
Test loss: 0.30017868733406067
Test accuracy: 0.901

Test loss: 0.30246967363357546
Test accuracy: 0.894

Test loss: 0.355930775642395
Test accuracy: 0.887
```

They're not super far apart I suppose, but I'd like to have full reproducibility. So, I tried to fix the seeds and reduce the multithreading using the following lines of code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random

seed = 124129
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed)
random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)
tf.set_random_seed(seed)
session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
K.set_session(sess)
```

I'm running this on my laptop which only has a CPU, so fixing the seeds should have been sufficient. However, the results seem to be even worse:

```
Test loss: 14.74805696105957
Test accuracy: 0.085

Test loss: 12.71728395843506
Test accuracy: 0.211

Test loss: 12.340894721984863
Test accuracy: 0.232
```

It's not just the fact that the accuracy is so low that is concerning, but also the fact that it's *still* not reproducible. What other sources of irreproducibility could there be?

For reference, here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/XixmKUC6